# Making an tornado proxy page

Tags: python, proxy, tornado, webproxy

**i want to make an tornado proxy page.**

So when I visit [proxypage](http://proxypage.com/http://google.com), I will get the content from google.com.

I made a small simple proxy page in php only to find out tornado webserver dont support php.
Here is t he php code to explain better what i'm looking for:

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents($_GET['requrl']);
echo $file;
?>
```

so its nothing to extreme.

I am making ajax requests to a site that gives json response, no images nothing special just json. but ajax dont work with cross-domain requests (same-origin-policy). and the site dont support jsonp or cors, so a proxy page is the only way.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/binux/3663115 It's a web proxy. I hope it's can help you.

Comment: Share you ajax code that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

add a handler that looks something like:

```
(r"/", proxyHandler ),
```

and the handler class

```
class proxyHandler(RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        connection = httplib.HTTPConnection( "www.google.com" )
        connection.request( 'GET', '[uri]', '[body]', '[header]' )
        response = connection.getresponse()

        if response.status !=200:
            print response.status, response.reason

        data = response.read()
        connection.close()

        try:
            dataJSON = json.loads(data)
            if DEBUG_HTTP:
                printDoc( dataJSON, 'http response json')

            return dataJSON
        except Exception, e:
            print 'data is of type, '+str(type(data))+', returning as is'
            return data
```

in connection.request() call, uri param is not optional ( can pass '' ), body and header are.
This could also be done in async fashion.